# How to apply a git patch relative

Tags: git, patch

I have the following scenario. I have two repositories. In the first one (A) I did some changes. The files I changed are also in the second repository (B) but in a different path i.e.:

```
a/dirA/dirB/file.cs
a/dirA/dirB/file2.cs
a/dirA/dirB/file3.cs
```

and in the other repository

```
b/dirC/dirB/file.cs
b/dirC/dirB/file2.cs
b/dirc/dirB/file3.cs
```

I already know that I can create a patch from `a/dirA` with `git diff` or `git format-patch` and the `--relative` option. But how to apply it to the files repository B?

Comment: Is it `git apply`?

Comment: @Philippe git apply doesn't work for me. If I call `git apply patchfile.patch` or `git apply < patchfile.patch` there is no error but also no changes